# How Iframe works in custom activity - Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I am quite new for custom activity.

I am trying to achieve the requirement that I need to save some data from Iframe through custom activity  to marketing cloud in DE (this part is done) and in second part ,need to fetch contact details as well as iframe details from marketing cloud and we need to create a JSON with iframe details and contact details.

After that need to send that JSON to third party server with REST API.Issue I am facing that how iframe will open and how it works and when custom activity executes second part .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine this data by adding inArguments to your save function in your customActivity.js file which will pull in the desired data from the entry event DE (or attribute group) as well as any values that you have fetched from your index.html file during configuration. Then you'd pass both of these in a payload to your primary execution function for further processing and sending to your external server.

```
connection.on('requestedTriggerEventDefinition',
    function(eventDefinitionModel) {
        if (eventDefinitionModel) {
            eventDefinitionKey = eventDefinitionModel.eventDefinitionKey;
        }
    });

function save() {
    var someValFromCAInput = $('#activityInput').val();
    payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
        "subscriberKey": "{{Event." + eventDefinitionKey + ".\"CustomerSubscriberKey\"}}",
        "prop": "{{Event." + eventDefinitionKey + ".\"SomeOtherEntryEventProp\"}}",
        "someVal": someValFromCAInput
    }];
    payload['metaData'].isConfigured = true;
    connection.trigger('updateActivity', payload);
}
```

Comment: I am trying with mentioned below payload but not getting values for email and contact key.. 'payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
                    "tokens": authTokens,
                    "Email": "{{Contact.Attribute." + '\"' + eventDefinitionKey + '\"' + ".\"Email\"}}",
                    "Contactkey": "{{Contact.Attribute." + '\"' + eventDefinitionKey + '\"' + ".\"ContactId\"}}",
                    "Header": header
                }];'       @Jason Hanshaw